# Trailhead project: Customize a Salesforce Object, Page Layout Error

Tags: page-layout, trailhead

I am currently doing the "Customize a Salesforce Object" project, on the step "Create Account Page Layouts" and I am getting the following error:

Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
Couldn't find the Partner Account Layout.

I'm not sure why this is as I have created the page layout with the correct name and with all the specifications.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue to the next step where you define the different record types, verify this step, then return back to the "Create Account Page Layouts" step and verify it. It will successfully let you pass this time.